# Why are there zero session entries in the highest page load times Google Analytics report?

Tags: google-analytics

I created an error dashboard with a widget that shows our pages with highest average page load time and over how many sessions this value was tracked.

But I do not know why Google Analytics shows zero sessions entries - what values are this?

[image: Avg. Pageload]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en) on support.google.com explains a similar effect on custom reports:

> If you build a custom report that has page level dimensions (such as
>   Page, Page Title, or a page level custom variable, Users may be
>   greater than Sessions. This may occur when combining Sessions with any
>   page level dimension because Sessions is incremented on, and
>   associated with, the first hit of the session.

It goes on to show that Session is only counted on the entrance page.

So, pages which no user has entered would show zero sessions.

Comment: So I should not use Session. I should use Hits (PageViews)?

Comment: Without knowing what you're wanting to convey, I can't say. I believe Hits will give the total number of page views, so a user who visits the page twice in a session will count as 2. Maybe 'Unique Pageviews' is closer to what you intended?